# How to simulate connectionTimeout in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, timeout, httpconnection

From my understanding, the `connectionTimeout` is the time for the first request to send after the connection. And if the period for the first request exceeds the `connectionTimeout`, an error will be thrown up.

Am I right? So, I write the following code snippet and it does not work.

Maybe I misunderstood some conceptions. Many thanks.

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8080/MVN.EXAMPLE/hello/HelloServlet").openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
try {   
    conn.connect();
    Thread.sleep(65*1000L); // the default connectionTimedout is 20s.
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
}
catch (Exception e) {
    int aaa = 0; // for debug
    // If connectionTimeout is triggered, it will go here.
}
finally {
    int bbb = 0; // for debug
}
```

The `URL` "http://127.0.0.1:8080/MVN.EXAMPLE/hello/HelloServle" is the path to my local application in `Tomcat`.

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
conn.connect();
Thread.sleep(65*1000L);
```

with this

```
  conn.setConnectTimeout(65 * 1000);
  conn.setReadTimeout(65 * 1000);
  conn.connect();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems no effect, and this is at the client-end. What's more, I want to see the native tomcat-end how to trigger connectionTimeout. Meanwhile, I tried fiddler to break before the request, but it still does not trigger the connectionTimeout from tomcat-end.

Answer (score 0):

I use telnet to simulate the connectionTimeout on tomcat-end.

1. Use telnet 127.0.0.1 8080
2. Wait connectionTimeout //The default is 20s
3. Telnet will close after 20s by foreign host
4. Repeat Step 1
5. Type GET /XXXX, and telnet will get the response

So, this can show that telnet only connects to the host without send the request.So, when the connectionTimeout is reached, the telnet client will close which is triggered by tomecat - it will automatically close the client.

Comment: A code snippet would have been nice.